# What are the major differences between the mysql and oracle sql dialects?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, dialect

I am a software developer. I have used mysql for years and now I am about to have my first encounter with oracle in a project.

I was just told that I should be careful that the sql behaves quite differently in some cases. I have no idea what to expect. I am mostly looking for obvious stuff and typical beginner mistakes.

For example I was told that oracle as no auto increment.

That's the type of stuff I am looking for. I'd be grateful for any further knowledge that helps avoid creating new solutions to problems already solved.

Answer (score 4):

> For example I was told that oracle as no auto increment.

Oracle has sequences; it's just a different notation.  The idea of a column value that's automatically incremented on INSERT is certainly there.

Oracle will have you add primary and foreign keys as constraints, separate from the table definition.

PostgreSQL is the closest thing to Oracle among the open source databases.  It, too, has sequences.

Comment: thanks, so I can create the auto-increment just in a different way that's good. to my great shame I have to admit so far I have only seen a tiny bit of sybase besides mysql

Comment: @duffymo, you can define constraints and PKs within the table definition if you wish. See inline constraint definitions here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm#sthref7519

Answer (score 0):

Grouping is a major difference, as MySQL has its own non-standard interpretation of grouping. So if you're using a lot of clever grouping, you might find that Oracle will not execute your queries.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: If you want to test Oracle-like grouping behavior in good old MySQL enable the `only_full_group_by` mode see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by